# Remove Textbox in Google Slide using App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-slides

How to remove the text box in google slides using App script?

After this I am saving it to pdf. I have to remove the text box for next flow.

```
var s = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation()
  var slide = s.getSlides()[0];

//Student Name
  slide
    .insertTextBox('Sai',100,100,100,10,10)
    .getText()
    .getTextStyle()
    .setFontSize(StudentName.fontSize);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- From `How to remove the text box in google slides using App script?`, I understood you want to remove the text box in Google Slides using Google Apps Script.

In your script, the text box is inserted. In this case, the text box is not removed. In order to remove the text box, I would like to propose the following sample script.

#### Modified script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var s = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation()
  var slide = s.getSlides()[0];
  slide.getShapes().forEach(shape => {
    if (shape.getShapeType() == SlidesApp.ShapeType.TEXT_BOX) {
      shape.remove();
    }
  });
}
```

- In this script, all text boxes are removed in 1st slide in Google Slides.
- If you want to remove all text boxes in all slides in Google Slides, you can use the following script.

  ```
    function myFunction() {
      var s = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation()
      var slides = s.getSlides();
      slides.forEach(slide => {
        slide.getShapes().forEach(shape => {
          if (shape.getShapeType() == SlidesApp.ShapeType.TEXT_BOX) {
            shape.remove();
          }
        });
      });
    }
  ```

#### Note:

- From `After this I am saving it to pdf. I have to remove the text box for next flow.`, in your situation, although I'm not sure about your whole script, before the Google Slides are exported as the PDF format, in order to reflect the latest Google Slides, it might be required to put `SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().saveAndClose()`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#saveandclose) Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [getShapeType()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape#getshapetype)
- [remove()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape#remove)

Comment: Thank You very much. It is working for my requirement. Yes, I am using "s.saveAndClose();" and 

var blob = DriveApp.getFileById("1zkIsdiSaVaK6W_R4du6VuyvK2leC3lBTg8fSzNCN6Zc").getBlob();
DriveApp.createFile(blob);

Now, I am using your code to remove text box. But it is not working after saveAndClose(). I am checking that now.